# What is the compatible keras_rl version with tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, keras-rl

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent

File ~\myenv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\__init__.py:2
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from .dqn import DQNAgent, NAFAgent, ContinuousDQNAgent
      3 from .ddpg import DDPGAgent
      4 from .cem import CEMAgent

File ~\myenv\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py:8
      5 from keras.models import Model
      6 from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Layer, Dense
----> 8 from rl.core import Agent
      9 from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy, GreedyQPolicy
     10 from rl.util import *

File ~\myenv\lib\site-packages\rl\core.py:8
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from keras.callbacks import History
----> 8 from rl.callbacks import (
      9     CallbackList,
     10     TestLogger,
     11     TrainEpisodeLogger,
     12     TrainIntervalLogger,
     13     Visualizer
     14 )
     17 class Agent(object):
     18     """Abstract base class for all implemented agents.
     19 
     20     Each agent interacts with the environment (as defined by the `Env` class) by first observing the
   (...)
     38         processor (`Processor` instance): See [Processor](#processor) for details.
     39     """

File ~\myenv\lib\site-packages\rl\callbacks.py:12
     10 from keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION
     11 from keras.callbacks import Callback as KerasCallback, CallbackList as KerasCallbackList
---> 12 from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
     15 class Callback(KerasCallback):
     16     def _set_env(self, env):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'
```

I am encountering a "ModuleNotFoundError" with the message "No module named keras.utils.generic_utils" when attempting to use the following libraries.

I suspect it might be a version compatibility issue. Currently, I have keras_rl==0.4.0, keras==2.14.0, and tensorflow==2.15.0.

Can anyone advise on the compatible versions of keras, tensorflow, and keras_rl that I should use?

Comment: Hi Nimasha Fernando, Its like a compatibility issue between the versions of the libraries what your using. Kindly use this versions for keras, tensor flow and keras-rl for set of compatible. you can try and let me know if still issue persists. Thanks.